# Spring data neo4j, search by date

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I have entity

```
 @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @GraphProperty
    private Long senderId;

    @GraphProperty
    private String subject;
    @GraphProperty
    private Date dateSent;
```

And I want search by userId and date between

my method is

```
List<Email> findBySenderIdAndDateSentBetween(Long userId, Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

but after calling it I have this exception

passed
newStartDate Fri Apr 27 00:00:00 AMST 2001
newEndDate Wed Apr 17 00:00:00 AMT 2013

```
"START `email`=node:__types__(className="com.backend.core.neo.entities.Email") WHERE `email`.`senderId`! = {0} AND `email`.`dateSent`! null {1} RETURN `email`"
                                                                                                                                       ^
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.query(CypherQueryEngine.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.dispatchQuery(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.DerivedCypherRepositoryQuery.execute(DerivedCypherRepositoryQuery.java:39)
```

without date it is work fine

I have converter in the frontend and my date pattern is yyyy-MM-dd .

I do not understand how can I solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I have added
 @GraphProperty(propertyType = java.util.Date.class)
    @Indexed
    private Date dateSent;
now no exception but result list is 0:(

Comment: How can I get date between with Spring data? Seems neo4j dislike dates?

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j only supports primitives and primitive arrays (+ Strings). For more information, see [the documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/preview/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html).

If you want to persist dates, represent them as longs.